# Unable to deploy a Java web SpringBootApplication on App Engine in Google Cloud Platform(GCP)

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine

My Spring boot Project::
Works fine locally as well as on **GCP** Cloud Shell.
But when I deploy it to ***flex env of AppEngine*** it gives deployment error.
Command used :: `mvn package appengine:deploy`
Following error is received::

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/spry-acolyte-283904/regions/europe-west1/operations/4983e962-e654-45cb-b6b4-ee17e71e18
7b error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /appengine-flex-v1/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-07-21T12:41:38.237Z74378.jc.9: Dep
loyment Manager operation spry-acolyte-283904/operation-1595335299281-5aaf2f1cfb28b-6e00c966-4034df10 errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
[INFO] GCLOUD: location: "/deployments/aef-default-1/resources/aef-default-1"
[INFO] GCLOUD: message: "{"ResourceType":"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"message":"The caller do
es not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/spry-acolyte
-283904/regions/europe-west1/autoscalers","httpMethod":"POST"}}"
[INFO] GCLOUD: ]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------

Below
```

I am using free tier, billing is not enabled , is it causing this issue.

Below is the pom.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
         <plugin>
                 <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                 <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.2.0</version>
                 <configuration>
                 <version>1</version>
                  <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
                 </configuration>
    </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

YAML is:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
```

Comment: Hi @asri I would recommend you to take a look at these similar cases [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/3272) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/281), and check if they can help you. Otherwise, please, raise an issue within the Github repository of the Maven plugin - you can do it [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/issues), so the developers can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the billing can be an issue as the Flexible environment [doesn't offer a free tier](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) and in addition, it's using Cloud Build in the background which requires billing.

If that doesn't solve the issue, can you make sure that you have the required permissions to deploy to App Engine as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/roles)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.
Was able to resolve this issue by changing the app.yaml to::

```
runtime: java
env: flex
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
    
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 5    
    
resources:
  memory_gb: 3
```

I guess it was not taking default automatic_scaling.